prove product of ab can be written in the same form as a,b
Problem: Let the integers $a$ and $b$ be represented as $x^2-5y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are integer numbers. Prove that the number $ab$ can also be presented in this form.
What I tried: I tried letting $a=x_1^2-5y_1^2$ and $b=x_2^2-5y_2^2$. Where $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ are integers. I multiplied them to get $(x_1x_2)^2-5(x_1y_2)^2-5(x_2y_1)^2+25(y_1y_2)^2$. I've tried different factorisations to get it into the form like $a,b$. For example: $(x_1x_2)^2-5[(x_1y_2)^2+(x_2y_1)^2-5(y_1y_2)^2]$ and trying to prove that the $[(x_1y_2)^2+(x_2y_1)^2-5(y_1y_2)^2]$ represents the $y^2$ and therefore is a square. But letting $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2=1$, doesn't make this a square, meaning there probably is another way of writing it. I need some help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity

Hint: $x^2-5y^2=(x+y\sqrt{5})(x-y\sqrt{5})$ writes your product with four factors, which you can pair differently.

You had already found: $ab=(x_1x_2)^2-5(x_1y_2)^2-5(x_2y_1)^2+25(y_1y_2)^2$. You should just exhibit $\left(x_1x_2-5y_1y_2\right)^2=(x_1x_2)^2+25(y_1y_2)^2-10x_1x_2y_1y_2$.
It immediately yield:
$$\begin{aligned}
ab&=(x_1x_2)^2-5(x_1y_2)^2-5(x_2y_1)^2+25(y_1y_2)^2\\&=(x_1x_2)^2
+25(y_1y_2)^2-10x_1x_2y_1y_2+10x_1x_2y_1y_2-5(x_1y_2)^2-5(x_2y_1)^2\\&=\left(
x_1x_2-5y_1y_2\right)^2-5\left((x_1y_2)^2+(x_2y_1)^2-2x_1x_2y_1y_2\right)\\&=
\left(x_1x_2-5y_1y_2\right)^2-5\left(x_1y_2-x_2y_1\right)^2&\text{ Q.E.D.}
\end{aligned}$$

Here is another method which is much nicer than bashing it out. First note that
$$x^2-5y^2=(x-y\sqrt5)(x+y\sqrt5)$$
Now,
$$\color{red}{(x_1^2-5y_1^2)}\color{blue}{(x_2^2-5y_2^2)}=\color{red}{(x_1-y_1\sqrt5)}\color{blue}{(x_2-y_2\sqrt5)}\color{red}{(x_1+y_1\sqrt5)}\color{blue}{(x_2+y_2\sqrt5)}$$
Multiply the first two brackets, and the last two.
$$\left((x_1x_2+5y_1y_2)-(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)\sqrt5\right)\left((x_1x_2+5y_1y_2)+(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)\sqrt5\right)$$
which by the very first equation we wrote, can be written as
$$(x_1x_2+5y_1y_2)^2-5(x_1y_2+x_2y_1)^2$$
as desired.

And this is no coincidence! Let us see in more generality of what this argument really tells us. Elements that look like $a+b\sqrt5$ for integers $a$ and $b$ form a ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt5]$. Similar to complex conjugation, there is the conjugation in this ring:
$$\overline{a+b\sqrt5}:=a-b\sqrt5$$
And once you have this, it is rather straightforward to see that $\overline{q_1q_2}=\overline{q_1}\cdot\overline{q_2}$. Then, we define the norm of an element as
$$N(a+b\sqrt5)=a^2-5b^2$$
Or $N(q)=q\overline{q}$. (Notice the similarity with the magnitude of a complex number $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$). It is obvious from this definition that $N(q_1q_2)=N(q_1)N(q_2)$.
Now, for your question, $a$ and $b$, being of the form $x^2-5y^2$, are norms of two elements of this ring, say $r$ and $s$ respectively. Then, $ab$ is just the norm of $rs$, and hence of the form $x^2-5y^2$. This is what we wrote down more explicitly in the first part of the answer.
Hope this helps. :)
